# Create multiple objects for a simulation

Tags: c++, eigen

Basically I wrote code to simulate one encoded data vector over a AWGN channel. The simulation but only works once. So I would like to create multiple objects or find a way to run the code multiple times depending on `int N` (for example `int N = 1000000;` in my case), so that I can calculate the BER (bit error rate).
I haven't found an elegant way to do that yet though...
I hope you understand my question. 
Do you need more information? 
Thank you!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "encode.h"
#include "awgn.h"
#include "decode.h"

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    std::string code = "Hamming";
    int dim_u, dim_mat_col, dim_mat_row, dim_mat_col_H, dim_mat_row_H;
    MatrixXi P;
    if (code == "Hamming")
    {
        dim_u = 4;       // can also call it "k"
        dim_mat_col = 7; // also serves as dim of x and y, or simply n
        dim_mat_row = 4;
        dim_mat_col_H = dim_mat_col;
        dim_mat_row_H = dim_mat_col - dim_mat_row;
        P = MatrixXi::Zero(dim_u, dim_mat_col - dim_u);
        P << 1, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1;
    }

    if (code == "BCH")
    {
        dim_u = 7;
        dim_mat_col = 15; // also serves as dim of x and y, or simply n
        dim_mat_row = 7;
        dim_mat_col_H = dim_mat_col;
        dim_mat_row_H = dim_mat_col - dim_mat_row;
        P = MatrixXi::Zero(dim_u, dim_mat_col - dim_u);
        P << 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1;
    }

    if (code == "Golay")
    {
        dim_u = 12;
        dim_mat_col = 24; // also serves as dim of x and y, or simply n
        dim_mat_row = 12;
        dim_mat_col_H = dim_mat_col;
        dim_mat_row_H = dim_mat_col - dim_mat_row;
        P = MatrixXi::Zero(dim_u, dim_mat_col - dim_u);
        P << 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
            1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1;
    }

    int N = 1000000; // number of simulations
    bool c_hat_minus_c = 0;
    int val = 0;

    Encode vec(dim_u, dim_mat_row, dim_mat_col);
    awgn channel(dim_mat_col);
    Decode dec(dim_mat_col, dim_mat_row_H, dim_mat_col_H, P);

    vec.encodeDataVector(dim_u, dim_mat_col, P);
    // std::cout << "modulated x: " << vec.x << std::endl;
    channel.addGausian(vec.x);
    // std::cout << channel.y << std::endl;

    c_hat_minus_c = dec.decodingalg(6000, channel.y, P, vec.x); // check if codeword is received correctly
                                                                //   std::cout << channel.y << std::endl;

    // std::cout << "val: " << val << std::endl;
}
```

If I wrap the stack allocated objects in a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Encode vec(dim_u, dim_mat_row, dim_mat_col);
        awgn channel(dim_mat_col);
        Decode dec(dim_mat_col, dim_mat_row_H, dim_mat_col_H, P);

        vec.encodeDataVector(dim_u, dim_mat_col, P);
        // std::cout << "modulated x: " << vec.x << std::endl;
        channel.addGausian(vec.x);
        // std::cout << channel.y << std::endl;

        c_hat_minus_c = dec.decodingalg(6000, channel.y, P, vec.x); // check if codeword is received correctly
                                                                    //   std::cout << channel.y << std::endl;

        // std::cout << "val: " << val << std::endl;
    }
```

The program breaks and says:

> /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CommaInitializer.h:97: Eigen::CommaInitializer& Eigen::CommaInitializer::operator,(const Eigen::DenseBase&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, -1>; XprType = Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, -1>]: Assertion `(m_col + other.cols() <= m_xpr.cols()) && "Too many coefficients passed to comma initializer (operator<<)"' failed.

Edit:
so I basically found out that it braks in `encode.cpp`
the second time it tries to initialize the Matrix G_

```
#include <iostream>
#include "encode.h"
#include "awgn.h"
#include <cstdlib> // rand and srand
#include <ctime>   // For the time function
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

Encode::Encode(int dim_u, int dim_mat_row, int dim_mat_col) //(7,4) Hamming code only up to now
{
    // if (code == "Hamming")
    //     dim_u = 4;
    // dim_mat_col = 7;
    // dim_mat_row = 4;

    u_ = RowVectorXi::Zero(dim_u);
    G_ = MatrixXi::Zero(dim_mat_row, dim_mat_col);
}

void Encode::encodeDataVector(int dim_u, int dim_mat_col, MatrixXi &P)
{

    // Get the system time.
    unsigned seed = time(0);

    // Seed the random number generator.
    srand(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < dim_u; i++)
    {
        u_(i) = rand() % 2; // only zeros and ones
    }
    // cout << u_ << endl << endl;

    MatrixXi I;

    //  I = MatrixXi::Zero(7, 7);
    I = MatrixXi::Identity(dim_u, dim_u);
    G_ << I, P; **<----- here**

    // cout << G_ << endl << endl;

    x = u_ * G_;

    for (int i = 0; i < dim_mat_col; i++)
    {
        x(i) = x(i) % 2;
    }

    // std::cout << "correct codeword: " << x << std::endl;

    // mapping for BPSK
    for (int i = 0; i < dim_mat_col; i++)
    {
        if (x(i) == 0)
            x(i) = 1;
        else
            x(i) = -1;
    }

    // awgn::awgn channel(dim_mat_col);
    // channel.addGausian(this->x);
}
```

Comment: At a guess I would say wrap everything below int N = ... inside a `for` loop and somehow accumulate the result.

Comment: I already tried that. But I'm not familiar with the lifetime of objects. Basically for every simulation I would need 3 new objects of `Encode` `awgn` and `Decode` as far as I understand it

Comment: By defining these variables inside the body of the for loop, every iteration gets a fresh set of objects that is cleaned up when the loop ends. Which is what you wanted, no?

Comment: Yes that's what I tried but I'm working with `Eigen` and after the first iteration it already breaks. It says "too many coefficients passed to comma initializer" ...I not sure where this happens and why

Comment: Now run your program in a debugger and wait until it catches the assertion; then move up the call stack until you find which of _your_ lines of code triggers it. From the structure of the code, it looks like the shape of `P` is being modified; in which case you can fix that by simply taking a copy of `P` at the top of the loop and passing that around.

Comment: Oh wow. I don't have any idea why this works but I just did what you suggested:
`MatrixXi P_copy;` and `P_copy = P;` at the top of the loop

Comment: `P` is being passed by non-const reference, which means it may be modified by the functions you call. Passing a copy of P in each iteration makes sure that the modifications to P stay local to that iteration.

Answer (score 0):

P is being passed by non-const reference, which means it may be modified by the functions you call. Passing a copy of P in each iteration makes sure that the modifications to P stay local to that iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    MatrixXi P_copy = P;
    ...
}
```